# Decision Split claims "non nullable attributes", any work arounds?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a Journey where I am trying to use a Decision Split to compare Journey Data to the Contact Data.

The field in question that I am trying to compare is not nullable, in either Contact Data and Journey Data DE's however I get

> Nullable Fields cannot be compared. One of these two fields is
> nullable

It appears this is a [known issue to Salesforce](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000KRe8QAG), but with no known workarounds or estimated time to fix. I would like to know if anyone else has come across this issue and know of ways to get around this? I have tried scrapping the Journey and starting over but this doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Why are you comparing journey and contact data?  Can you describe the entry source?

Comment: The journey can have multiple instances of the Subscriber, they are entered when they create a Case record in SF. I want to use a decision split for each instance for of a case to dictate actions based on case status.